# Android Layout: same device size family, different real device sizes

Tags: android, android-layout

Just a quick question:
My application should work both for my device (Galaxy Ace - 320 x 480 - "**Normal**" screen size family) and for the Galaxy Nexus (720 x 1280 - "**Normal**" screen size family).
I wrote two layouts in two different folders: *layout* and *layout-sw600dp*.
Unfortunately the Galaxy Nexus keep to choose the xml definition in the "*layout*" folder instead of "*layout-sw600dp*" one.

How can I solve this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Without checking any details, are you sure you have to _solve_ something? The _normal_ etc terminology refers to `dp`, not `px`. So the behaviour might be correct. I'm just telling you this because you mix `px` and `dp` in your question, so you might already know this.

Comment: The question is: how can I make the Galaxy Nexus choose a different layout xml file (not the one in "layout" folder)?

Comment: The answer is: By placing it into a resource folder in which it will look for it. _density_ may be suitable if my guess is right. [Here[(http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) are the rules. And logging the [DisplayMetrics](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/DisplayMetrics.html) will help you to figure what the device will choose.

Comment: Perfect, copied. I was a little bit confused. So, the right answer is: place it in a folder called: "layout-xhdpi". Now it works, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

(Thanks to @Class Stacker)

For everyone who has the same issue: put the layout xml file for the Galaxy Nexus in a folder called "layout-xhdpi".